# How to parse multiple files in Perl

Tags: perl, parsing

I have this sample data I wanted to parse and there are more than 10 files like this, how can I parse them? I need the second line of the data and extract only code, date and message.

[image]

```
foreach my $dir (@not_proc_dir) {
    chomp ($dir);
    print "$dir\n";

    opendir (DIR, $dir) or die "Couldn't open directory, $!";
    while ( my $file = readdir DIR) {
            next if $file =~ /^\.\.?$/;
    #       next if (-d $file);
            next if -d "$dir/$file";
            #print "\t$file\n";
            $file = "${dir}/${file}";
            if ($file =~ /\.err/) {
                    parse_err($file);
            }
            elsif ($file =~ /\.xml$/) {
                    parse_xml($file);
            }
            elsif ($file =~ /\.enrich/){
                    parse_enrich($file);
            }
    }
    close DIR;

sub parse_err {
         my $xml = shift;
        my @array = open(DATA, $xml) or die "Couldn't open file $xml, $!";
        my $secLine;
        foreach(@array) {
                my $secLine = $_;
                last;
        }
        close DATA;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the current code?

Comment: i can only parse 1 not the entire line

Comment: `I need the second line of the data and extract only code, date and message.` you need firstline or second line

Comment: sorry i edited the sample code. I mean second line the one i highlighted in my screenshot

Comment: Don't post images of text. Please replace it with the text itself.

Comment: *i can only parse 1 not the entire line* But I thought you only wanted to parse one line (the second line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[open](http://p3rl.org/open) doesn't return the lines of the file. You need to use [readline](http://p3rl.org/readline).

```
open my $in, '<', $xml or die "Can't open $xml: $!";
<$in>;  # Ignore the first line.
my $second_line = <$in>;
```

The diamond operator `<$in>` is a shorter version of `readline $in`.

Comment: i can now parse the entire second line :)

Comment: should i make it an array so that i can select the code, date and message?

Comment: To ask a new question, create a new question :)

Comment: i was able to create a new variable pass value to it and display the code, date and message

Answer (score 2):

This subroutine is very strange.

```
sub parse_err {
    my $xml = shift;
    my @array = open(DATA, $xml) or die "Couldn't open file $xml, $!";
    my $secLine;
    foreach (@array) {
        my $secLine = $_;
        last;
    }
    close DATA;
}
```

[`open()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) simply returns a true or false value, indicating whether the file was opened successfully. Storing that return value in an array makes no sense.

You then declare a variable called `$secLine` that you never use.

You then iterate across the contents of `@array` (which only has one element in it, so the loop only executes once).

In the loop body, you declare another variable called `$secLine` and copy the value from the array into that variable. You then exit the loop - so your second variable called `$secLine` goes out of scope and ceases to exist. This effectively means that your loop has no effect whatsoever.

All in all, you seem very confused. If this is coursework, then I recommend you go back through your class notes and have a closer look at the section about reading data from files.

I think you want something like this:

```
sub parse_err {
  my ($filename) = @_;

  open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Could'nt open file '$filename': $!\n";

  <$fh>; # Read and ignore first line.
  my $line = <$fh>; # Read second line

  my (undef, $code, undef, $date, $time, $message) = split /\s+/, $line, 6;

  $date = "$date $time";

  return ($code, $date, $message);
}
```

This subroutine returns three values - `$code`, `$date` and `$message`. You'll need to assign those to variables as you call the subroutine and then do something useful with them.

```
my ($code, $date, $message) = parse_err($file);
```

Answer (score 1):

Attn: OP

In feature please provide sample of input data in text format (copy+paste from terminal windows).

The code is very simple to implement with perl script

> define regex of interest
>
> look for '*.err' files
>
> - open file
> - look for pattern
> - extract data
> - print out found data

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $re = qr/\d\s+(\d{4})\s+E\s+(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4})\s+(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})\s+(.*)/;

for my $filename ( glob("*.err") ) {
    say '------------------';
    say $filename;
    say '------------------';
    open my $fh, '<', $filename
        or die "Couldn't open $filename : $!";
    
    while( <$fh> ) {
        chomp;
        next unless /$re/;
        my($code,$date,$time,$msg) = ($1,$2,$3,$4);
        say 'Code: '    . $code;
        say 'Date: '    . $date;
        say 'Time: '    . $time;
        say 'Message: ' . $msg;
        say '------------------';
    }
    
    close $fh;
}
```

Input data

```
4   0
1   9001    E   10-17-2019  23:15:39    ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into
Error at character 139 of the following SQL;
insert into lot (lot_key, lot_id, part_cnt,
.....
1   9001    E   10-17-2019  23:15:39    Error Executing lot_put_row 2
1   9001    E   10-17-2019  23:15:39    DBASCII: Exit called from file ora/dbreader.pc at line 10666
Version 2.6.2 - April 26, 2017 (DB schema 10.6rl)
1   9001    E   10-17-2019  23:15:39
ROLLBACK was successfill
```

Output

```
------------------
ora-err-01400.err
------------------
Code: 9001
Date: 10-17-2019
Time: 23:15:39
Message: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into
------------------
Code: 9001
Date: 10-17-2019
Time: 23:15:39
Message: Error Executing lot_put_row 2
------------------
Code: 9001
Date: 10-17-2019
Time: 23:15:39
Message: DBASCII: Exit called from file ora/dbreader.pc at line 10666
------------------
```